# how to update neural network by training step

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have to run a code by using following parameters. I have understanding of Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD) method in which we send a mini batch of sample and calculate the gradient for this mini batch and assume as it is for whole training samples. And after calculating gradient we update. In following code mini batch is 2000 so we are bound to update after sending 2000  samples initially. I'm confused that what this training step is deciding here?

```
parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=2000,help='batch size of training (default 2000)')
parser.add_argument('--training_step', type=int, default=4000,help='training steps (default 4000)')
```

Comment: You can to plot the error with the training steps with training steps to see how the error goes down over iteration?

Comment: In SGD our goal is to reduce error and get global minina. Does this training step means learning rate?I have understanding of learning rate in terms of a maths function that it is the size of jump. But how can i explain this in terms of machine learning?training step 4000 means we are make large variation in weights?

Comment: Sorry to ask such a naive question. I'm trying to understand it from the last few days but still not clear. I will be thankful if you please explain this by giving a simple example.

Comment: So first, number of steps is not learning rate. Learning rate is how much weight you give to the gradient e.g. `alpha * gradient`, `alpha` is a learning rate in this case. Batch size is the sample size you sample in order to calculate the gradient in SGD. In each step, you sample data and calculate the gradient. So the more steps (with right learning rate), will hopefully bring the cost function down over the iterations (which I guess defined with `training_step` parameter).

Comment: so training step means that we are taking 4000 steps towards global minima. Does this training step gives me any information about the weights update? because after calculating gradient of a batch size that is 100 in above example. i update weights and calculate loss function.Can i tell from above information that how many times i have updated?

Comment: @titipat can you please explain this to me.I'm stuck in these these and trying to understand this from the last couple of days.

Comment: Any explanation for my question. I'll be really thankful. I can't understand the code without having clear understanding of these questions.

Comment: yes, we're taking 4000 steps toward global minima. So, the weight updates depends on how many sample from dataset you take from full dataset (batch size). This varies with different dataset.

Comment: So, you have to plot cost function over iteration in order to see how your cost function goes down over iteration (training steps).

Comment: ok. i got it. Thanks for your help